# I Want to pass a Rxlist One page to another page

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

RxList<Map<String, dynamic>> selectedAddress = <Map<String, dynamic>>[].obs;

```
   Map<String, dynamic> newObj = addressController.addressData[index];
                                selectedAddress.add(newObj);
```

in this list selectedAddress has seted sucesfull i want to use this in another page

in this list selectedAddress has seted sucesfull i want to use this in another page

Comment: what is your page name or class name in which you want to use

Answer (score 0):

You can pass this list while navigating to another screen like this:

```
Get.toNamed(Routes.DETAILS, arguments: {
  'selected_address': selectedAddress,
});
```

Now from the second screen, you can access this data like this:

```
class SecondScreenController extends GetxController {
  RxList<Map<String, dynamic>> newObj = Get.arguments['selected_address'] ?? [].obs;
}
```

You can go through [this doc](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/routing-and-navigation-with-getx-in-flutter/#:%7E:text=To%20navigate%20to%20a%20named,parameters%20as%20a%20second%20parameter) to understand this better.